# Which is the fastest way to count elements in array

Tags: python

I have a massive list which contains a country_names, many times. 
I would like to create a new list (smaller) which will contain a sum for how many times a country is included in the bigger list.

```
[
      {
          "country_name": "US"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "US"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "GERMANY"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "GERMANY"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "GERMANY"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "ITALY"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "ITALY"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "ITALY"
      },
      {
          "country_name": "ITALY"
      }
]
```

which is the fastest way to generate a new list with this data. I would like something like this: I can do it with a for loop but it is way too slow. Any alternatives ?

```
[
      {
          "country_name": "US",
          "count": 2
      },
      {
          "country_name": "GERMANY",
          "count": 3
      },
      {
          "country_name": "ITALY",
          "count": 4
      },
]
```

Comment: keep it in something more useful - at least `list` like `["US", "US", ...]` and use `list.count()` or you can try with `collections.Counter()`. Eventually use `pandas.DataFrame` or keep in database - and then they will use code created in C/C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have big file to check speed and compare which one is faster

---

You can try to use `collections.Counter` but it would need `for`-loop to get value from directiories.

```
data = [
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
]

import collections

c = collections.Counter([x["country_name"] for x in data])

print(c)
```

Result:

```
Counter({'ITALY': 5, 'GERMANY': 3, 'US': 2})
```

---

You could also convert to `pandas.DataFrame` (or read from file/database directly to `DataFrame`) and make all "calculations" with `pandas` which uses fast code created in `C/C++/Fortran`

```
data = [
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print(df)

print( df['country_name'].value_counts() )
```

Result:

```
ITALY      5
GERMANY    3
US         2
Name: country_name, dtype: int64
```

---

Other method is to keep data in database and use `SQL` for this - usually database engine is faster then Python's loop.

```
SELECT country_name, COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY country_name
```

---

```
data = [
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
]

import sqlite3


def init(db, data):
    cur = db.cursor()

    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data')

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, country_name STRING)')

    for item in data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO data (country_name) VALUES (?)', (item['country_name'], ))

    db.commit()

    cur.close()

# ---

db = sqlite3.Connection('data.db')

init(db, data)  # use it only once

cur = db.cursor()

#result = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data')
result = cur.execute('SELECT country_name, COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY country_name')
for row in result:
    print('row:', row)

cur.close()
```

Result:

```
row: ('GERMANY', 3)
row: ('ITALY', 5)
row: ('US', 2)
```

---

**EDIT:** Other method is to use faster server then local computer - for example free [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Comment: I added example with database SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is usually quite fast for counting:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

countries = [
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "US"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "GERMANY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
    {"country_name": "ITALY"},
]

counts = defaultdict(int)
for country in countries:
    counts[country["country_name"]] += 1

pprint([{"country_name": k, "count": v} for k, v in counts.items()])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'count': 2, 'country_name': 'US'},
 {'count': 3, 'country_name': 'GERMANY'},
 {'count': 5, 'country_name': 'ITALY'}]
```